# bash scripting find a line that has a count higher than x for y occurance and then replace anything after a certain point with z

Tags: bash, replace, find, append, edit

Example of what I am trying to do

(Note: The numbering is **not** part of the actual code.)

---

`cat program.nasm`

```
1. "\x61\x6e\x69\x6e\x67\x2c\x20\x74\x68\x65"
2. "\x20\x6f\x6e\x6c\x79\x20\x70\x61\x72\x74"
3. "\x20\x74\x68\x61\x74\x20\x6d\x65\x61\x6e"
4. "\x73\x6f\x6d\x65\x74\x68\x69\x6e\x67\x20\x69\x73\x20\x77\x68\x61"
5. "\x74\x20\x69\x73\x20\x63\x6f\x6e\x74\x61\x69\x6e\x65\x64\x20\x69"
6. "\x6e\x20\x74\x68\x65\x20\x73\x74\x61\x63\x6b\x20\x6f\x76\x65\x72\xf2"
7. "\x66\x6c\x6f\x77\x20\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x69\x6f\x6e"
8. this is random characters that is longer than line 6 to make things
challenging
```

---

- the first 3 lines have 10 bytes
- the 4th and 5th lines have 16 bytes
- the 6th line has more than 16 bytes
- the 7th line may be as much as 16 bytes or it will be less
- the 8th line has a long character set

In short, I need something that will

- 1st search for a line that has "\x" more than 16 times
- 2nd delete everything after that point (characters count = 16 * 4 + 1
  = 65)
- 3rd add a quotation mark at the end.

---

This is what I want it to look like
notice line 6, it is the only one that is different

`cat program.nasm`

```
1. "\x61\x6e\x69\x6e\x67\x2c\x20\x74\x68\x65"
2. "\x20\x6f\x6e\x6c\x79\x20\x70\x61\x72\x74"
3. "\x20\x74\x68\x61\x74\x20\x6d\x65\x61\x6e"
4. "\x73\x6f\x6d\x65\x74\x68\x69\x6e\x67\x20\x69\x73\x20\x77\x68\x61"
5. "\x74\x20\x69\x73\x20\x63\x6f\x6e\x74\x61\x69\x6e\x65\x64\x20\x69"
6. "\x6e\x20\x74\x68\x65\x20\x73\x74\x61\x63\x6b\x20\x6f\x76\x65\x72"
7. "\x66\x6c\x6f\x77\x20\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x69\x6f\x6e"
8. this is random characters that is longer than line 6 to make things
challenging
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to do with this? :)

Comment: Using shell script to modify a binary sounds like an absolutely terrible idea.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

sed oneliner -

```
sed -r 's/^("(\\x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]){16}).*/\1"/'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '$0 ~ /(\\x[0-9a-f]{2}){17}/ {$0=substr($0,1,65)"\""; print}' foo
"\x61\x6e\x69\x6e\x67\x2c\x20\x74\x68\x65"
"\x20\x6f\x6e\x6c\x79\x20\x70\x61\x72\x74"
"\x20\x74\x68\x61\x74\x20\x6d\x65\x61\x6e"
"\x73\x6f\x6d\x65\x74\x68\x69\x6e\x67\x20\x69\x73\x20\x77\x68\x61"
"\x74\x20\x69\x73\x20\x63\x6f\x6e\x74\x61\x69\x6e\x65\x64\x20\x69"
"\x6e\x20\x74\x68\x65\x20\x73\x74\x61\x63\x6b\x20\x6f\x76\x65\x72"
"\x66\x6c\x6f\x77\x20\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x69\x6f\x6e"
this is random characters that is longer than line 6 to make things challenging
```

What it does:

- 1st searches for a line that has "\x" more than 16 times
- 2nd deletes everything after that point (characters count = 16 * 4 + 1 = 65)
- 3rd adds a quotation mark at the end
- 4th prints

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.